# Code::Blocks: Cannot open file: ../libgcc/unwind-sjlj.c

Tags: c++, recursion, compiler-errors, binary-tree

I've been working on this project for a bit now and I'm running into this issue that I can't solve.

As a preface, the program builds a binary tree from data from a file, then the tree can grow, and the new complete information is written over that original file.

To do this all with a single information vector, I'm having my input vector be ordered in level order, however (as far as I understand, please correct me if I'm wrong), in order to do this, I need to have the NULL spaces accounted for in my vector, and to rewrite everything correctly I need faux-NULL (nodes that fill space but don't contain any actual information other than pointers) nodes on my tree.

When the tree grows, then, I'm trying to complete and balance it with "NULL" nodes, and I do so recursively with an in-order traversal and the depth in mind. When I run this, however, I'm getting a Segmentation Fault, and when I run it step by step with the debugger, I'm getting

`Cannot open file: ../../../../../src/gcc-4.9.2/libgcc/unwind-sjlj.c`

specifically. It occurs when, during the recursive traversal, the algorithm adds a node, and upon reaching the "return" portion of the node's memory allocator, the error pops up and the program breaks.

Is this an error with my code or is it an error with Code::Blocks' libraries?

Relevant code:

```
struct Node
{
    int idx; //idx is information relevant to the program but not to the structure
    std::string phrase;
    Node* left, * right;
};

Node* newNode(std::string data, int idx) //memory allocator
{
    Node* node = new Node;
    node->phrase = data;
    node->idx = idx;
    node->left = node->right = NULL;
    return (node); //right here is where the debugger gives me the error
}

// Function to insert nodes in level order
Node* insertLevelOrder(std::string arr[], int idx[], Node* root,int i, int n)
{
    // Base case for recursion
    if (i < n)
    {
        Node* temp = newNode(arr[i],idx[i]);
        root = temp;

        // insert left child
        root->left = insertLevelOrder(arr,idx,root->left, 2 * i + 1, n);

        // insert right child
        root->right = insertLevelOrder(arr,idx,root->right, 2 * i + 2, n);
    }
    return root;
}

int calcularProfundidad(Node * root) //Sorry for the spanglish--this is "calculateDepth"
{
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    int h1 = calcularProfundidad(root->left); //recursively calculate depth of left subtree
    int h2 = calcularProfundidad(root->right); //and of right subtree

    return 1 + max(h1,h2);
}

void rellenarNulos(Node * root, int prof, int counter) //fills "empty spaces" with "faux-NULL" nodes
{
    if(counter == prof) //if reaches depth, stops, if not, adds more nodes
        return;
    if(root->left == NULL && counter < prof)
    {
        Node * auxNode = newNode("NULL",0); //error in this call
        root->left = auxNode;
    }
    if(root->right == NULL && counter < prof)
    {
        Node * auxNode2 = newNode("NULL",0);
        root->right = auxNode2;
    }
    rellenarNulos(root->left,prof,counter++);
    rellenarNulos(root->right,prof,counter++);
}


#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "arbLib.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //Builds tree from file
    int N;
    fstream myfile ("test.txt");
    if (!myfile.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Unable to open file" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    myfile >> N; //N is the number of nodes 
    string words[N];
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
        myfile >> words[i];
    int nums[N];
    for(int j=0;j<N;j++)
        myfile >> nums[j];
    myfile.close();

    //Builds tree from these vectors that are level order
    Node *root = insertLevelOrder(words,nums,root,0,N);


    int prof = calcularProfundidad(root); //calculates depth

    rellenarNulos(root,prof,1); //here is where the program dies 

    inOrder(root);

    destroyTree(root);

    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```